# Connecting client app to my server made in java

Tags: java, sockets

A few days ago at uni we did this simple client-server app. The app allows you to request info from the server and get a response. We tested it on our own machines (localhost) as well as test them in a local network. Everything worked fine and we were able to send info from one computer to another in our local network. I wanted to use the app at home and communicate with a friend. The problem that we have is that we are unable to connect to one another and we always get the connection timeout error.

We have tried different things until now :

- Disable firewall

  - Give permission to java in the firewall
  - Tried different ports
  - Tried different client-server apps that give us the exact same problem
  - Changed networks entirely (connected from different routers)
    We are using the external IP (not the local one) and we are able to ping each other's addresses.

Here is the code for the server :

```
public class ServermultifilarTCP1 extends Thread {           
    private Scanner scanTCP;
    private PrintStream printTCP;
    private Socket socketTCP;
    private static Orar orar = new Orar();

    public ServermultifilarTCP1(Socket conexiuneTCP) throws IOException {
        this.socketTCP = conexiuneTCP;        // Obtinere socket
        this.scanTCP = new Scanner(socketTCP.getInputStream());
        this.printTCP = new PrintStream(socketTCP.getOutputStream());
    }

    public void run() {
        String mesaj;
        int zi;

        try {
             while(true) {
                if (scanTCP.hasNextLine()) {
                    mesaj = scanTCP.nextLine();
                    if (mesaj.equals("getOrar")) {
                        try {
                            zi = Integer.parseInt(scanTCP.nextLine());
                            String rezultat = orar.getOrar(zi);
                            printTCP.println(rezultat);
                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                            printTCP.println("Stop");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            socketTCP.close();    // Inchiderea socketului si a fluxurilor
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server: Bye!");
        } catch (IOException ex) {  ex.printStackTrace();   }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int portTCP = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(

                         "Server: introduceti numarul de port al serverului"));

        ServerSocket serverTCP = new ServerSocket(portTCP); // Creare socket server

        while (true) {

            Socket conexiune = serverTCP.accept();

            ServermultifilarTCP1 server = new ServermultifilarTCP1(conexiune);

            server.start();

        }

    }

}
```

And here is the Client class:

```
package pachetorar;



import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.net.*;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;



public class ClientTCP1 {

    private Scanner scanTCP;

    private PrintStream printTCP;

    private Socket socketTCP;

    private int portTCP;

    private InetAddress adresaIP;

    private JFrame frame;



    public ClientTCP1() throws IOException {     

        this.portTCP = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(

                       "Client: introduceti numarul de port al serverului"));

        this.adresaIP = InetAddress.getByName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(

                       "Client: introduceti adresa serverului"));

        this.socketTCP = new Socket(adresaIP, portTCP);        // Creare socket

        this.scanTCP = new Scanner(socketTCP.getInputStream());

        this.printTCP = new PrintStream(socketTCP.getOutputStream());



        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Client TCP");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container containerCurent = frame.getContentPane();

        containerCurent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());



        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        final JLabel eticheta = new JLabel("Orarul zilei de:");

        pane.add(eticheta);



        final int numButtons = 8;

        final JRadioButton[] radioButtons = new JRadioButton[numButtons];

        final ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();



        radioButtons[0] = new JRadioButton("Luni");

        radioButtons[0].setActionCommand("0");

        radioButtons[1] = new JRadioButton("Marti");

        radioButtons[1].setActionCommand("1");

        radioButtons[2] = new JRadioButton("Miercuri");

        radioButtons[2].setActionCommand("2");

        radioButtons[3] = new JRadioButton("Joi");

        radioButtons[3].setActionCommand("3");

        radioButtons[4] = new JRadioButton("Vineri");

        radioButtons[4].setActionCommand("4");

        radioButtons[5] = new JRadioButton("Sambata");

        radioButtons[5].setActionCommand("5");

        radioButtons[6] = new JRadioButton("Duminica");

        radioButtons[6].setActionCommand("6");

        radioButtons[7] = new JRadioButton("Stop");

        radioButtons[7].setActionCommand("Stop");

        radioButtons[0].setSelected(true);



        for (int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++) {

            group.add(radioButtons[i]);

            pane.add(radioButtons[i]);

        }

        containerCurent.add(pane, BorderLayout.WEST);



        JButton sendButton = new JButton("Trimite");



        sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            // trimiterea catre server a cererii de efectuare a serviciului

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String service = "getOrar";

                printTCP.println(service);

                String command = group.getSelection().getActionCommand();

                printTCP.println(command);

            }

        });

        containerCurent.add(sendButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);



        final JTextArea outGrafic = new JTextArea(8, 40); // Zona non-editabila

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(outGrafic,

                     JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,

                     JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        outGrafic.setEditable(false);

        containerCurent.add(outGrafic, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack(); frame.setVisible(true);



        String mesaj;

        while(true) {                     // afisarea raspunsului primit de la server

            if (scanTCP.hasNextLine()) {

                mesaj = scanTCP.nextLine();

                outGrafic.setText(outGrafic.getText() + mesaj + "\n");

                if (mesaj.equals("Stop")) System.exit(0);  // Conditie oprire

            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ClientTCP1 client = new ClientTCP1();

    }
}
```

Here is a class used by the server class but it isn't relevant to the problem I think:

```
package pachetorar; public class Orar {

    private String[] orar; // camp ascuns (starea obiectului)



    public Orar() {

        orar = new String[7]; // alocarea dinamica a spatiului pentru tablou

        // popularea tabloului cu valori

        orar[0] = "Luni este curs TPI la seriile D si E " +

                                "si laborator TPI la seria E.";

        orar[1] = "Marti nu sunt ore de TPI.";

        orar[2] = "Miercuri este laborator TPI la seriile D si E.";

        orar[3] = "Joi este laborator TPI la seria D.";

        orar[4] = "Vineri este laborator TPI la seria D.";

        orar[5] = "Sambata nu sunt ore de TPI.";

        orar[6] = "Duminica nu sunt ore de TPI.";

    }

    public String getOrar(int zi) { // metoda accesor - getter

        return orar[zi];            // returneaza un element al tabloului

    }

    public void setOrar(int zi, String text) { // metoda accesor - setter

        orar[zi] = text;                       // inlocuieste un element

    }

}
```

The desired result should be establishing a connection between the two computers and not getting the connection timeout error.If the client cant communicate with the server, the gui wont show up and i would get the error mentioned above.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are both computers behind NAT?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding. Idea is to configure router handling server network to redirect all incoming packages send to some port, to specific internal IP (internal server IP) and its port. So if your client is trying to connect to `serverExternalIP:somePort` then let router redirect all TCP (or UDP) packages send to `somePort` to `serverIP:portOnWhichServerListens`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely need to open the port, and then port forward in your router's settings. What this does is tell your router that any connection coming in on the port you choose to use should redirect to your machine.

For example, if I were to open port x, and then forward that to my computer's local IP address, any inbound connection to my public IP using port x would be redirected to the application running on that port on my computer.

Comment: I tried forwarding and used this https://portforward.com. The port still appears as closed when I am trying to check if it is open or not tho. Does the client side need to port forward as well?

Comment: Try turning on your application, and then test to see if it is open while the app is still running.

Answer (score 0):

Since your computers are behind NAT, you can't access your friend's computer directly. You should use [Network address translator traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) or [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding). Or both pc should be in the same physical network (you can use VPN as well).